# SELECT ALL with SUM(Col)

Tags: sql, select, sum

Is there a way to Select all and also get the sum of a column all in the same query?

```
SELECT *, SUM(Colname) FROM `Table`...
```

Thank you.

Comment: This really should be two queries. Any solution will likely be a horrible abuse of a sub-query. The real question is why would you want the sum to show up next to every row? If you were outputting a table, would you want every row in the table to have the same sum value?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? This can easily be done with a window function.

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done using a window function:

```
select t.*, 
       sum(some_value) over () as total_sum
from some_table as t;
```

This is standard SQL and works on all modern DBMS.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c1a74/1

Comment: You taught me something new.  Thanks for that and +1 for you.  I never saw that use of `over ()`

Answer (score 0):

No, if you want to use aggregate functions then you have to `GROUP BY` and end up getting a single row for the columns you have specified in that `GROUP BY col1, col2, col3`.

If you want multiple records (`SELECT *`) and also want the `SUM(Colname)` of one of them then do it in 2 separate queries.

Comment: I think you can do that with a subquery as I showed in my answer

Comment: @CrApHeR just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I totally agree with you.  I don't like and I would not do that, but as you said you can do it.  If I have to do that for sure I would use 2 queries as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that with a subquery

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Table,
    (SELECT 
        SUM(Colname) SumColumn
    FROM 
        Table) t1
```

I tested in SQL Server with this small example

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (IntData INT, Data NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #Test(IntData, Data)
SELECT 1, 'Data1' UNION
SELECT 3, 'Data2' UNION
SELECT 5, 'Data3' UNION
SELECT 7, 'Data4' UNION
SELECT 9, 'Data5' UNION
SELECT 11, 'Data6'

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    #Test,
    (SELECT 
        SUM(IntData) SumIntData
    FROM 
        #Test) t1

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Hope this helps